Is there a convention of using (x1,x2) for a column vector, not row?
I know square brackets and round brackets are mostly interchangeable for vectors or matrices but this is different.
In Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang (https://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila6/indexila6.html), which consistently uses square brackets for vectors and matrices, there is this part (it is on the page 4 of 14, numbered vii within the page,  in the sample PDF on the website)
(begin quote)
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 7 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 3& -1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 4 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & −1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
 =CR
$$
Column 3 of $A$ is dependent on columns 1 and 2 of $A$, and column 3 of R shows how.
Add the independent columns 1 and 2 of C to get column $a_3 = a_1 + a_2 = (3, 7, 3)$ of $A$.
(end quote)
I'm puzzled by the last part, "$a_3 = a_1 + a_2 = (3, 7, 3)$ of $A$". I think it can equivalently be written $a_3 = a_1 + a_2 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\7\\3\end{bmatrix}$, or $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 7 & 3 \end{bmatrix}^\intercal$.  I would be happier if it had a transpose  like $(3,7,3)^\intercal$.
This notation using round round brackets and comma to write down a column vector in a row, appears not infrequently in the book, but I wasn't able to find any remark on the notation.
So, is there a convention to write $(a,b,c)$ to denote a column vector, not row? Also, I've seen  other materials that actually uses $(a,b,c)$ (including the comma) to a row vector (like, $\boldsymbol a = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots  \\a_N\end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol a ^\intercal = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N)$). How can I distinguish the two notations? If I see $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, x_2, \dots x_d)$ in other documents, which should I think it is?

Sadly, it's something I struggle with a bit too: some people by default assume $(x,y,\cdots,z)$ is a column vector, some assume by default it is a row vector, and almost none of them clarify which and they just expect you to pick it up from context. Quite infuriating. Sometimes I do like to specify that, say, $(x,y,\cdots,z) \in \mathbb{F}^{1 \times n}$ to specify a $1$-row, $n$-column row vector, or $(x,y,\cdots,z) \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times 1}$ for a $n$-row, $1$-column column vector (as opposed to merely $\mathbb{F}^n$ in either case) to at least distinguish it a bit somewhat.

It states that they're column vectors directly so there is no ambiguity here. When commas are used I don't consider it a matrix.

I would write $(3\ 7\ 3)$ for a row vector, and $(3,7,3)$ for a column vector.
